# sorting array after array_count_values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array of products

```
$products = array_count_values($products);
```

now I have an array where $key is product number and $value is how many
times I have such a product in the array.
I want to sort this new array that product with the least "duplicates" are
on the first place, but what ever I use (rsort, krsort,..) i loose product
numbers (key).

any suggestions?

thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take a look at [`arsort()`](http://php.net/arsort) as an alternative to [`rsort()`](http://php.net/rsort) (and that family of functions).

Generally, the '[**Sorting arrays**](http://php.net/array.sorting)' page on php.net might be useful to you - it's a comparison of PHP's array sorting functions based on what they sort, what direction they sort in, and whether they maintain the keys while sorting.

---

Mind you, for the sake of completion:

Going by '*now I have an array where $key is product number and $value is how many times I have such a product in the array. I want to sort this new array that product with the least "duplicates" are on the first place*', you probably want [**`asort()`**](http://php.net/asort) (the pendant to [`sort()`](http://php.net/sort)).

---

Your comment example, using **`asort()`**:

```
$arr = array(
    1 => 3,
    2 => 2,
    5 => 3,
    9 => 1
);
asort($arr);
print_r($arr);
```

yields:

```
Array
(
    [9] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [1] => 3
    [5] => 3
)
```

Comment: Hi thanx for quick reply
 i have checked arsort() but not returning the required result any suggestions??

Comment: @umermalik: Just making sure I understand what you're saying: You get the correct result with `rsort()` (excepting the keys), but not with `arsort()`?

Comment: `arsort()` sorts from *highest* to *lowest*, but the OP wants from *lowest* to *highest*. Hence `asort()` is the proper function to use.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Yeah, it was my first assumption, too, but the emphasis was on the lost keys. 'what ever I use (rsort, krsort,..) i loose product numbers (key)'. So I figured I'd mention the family and general way to solve the key-loss problem rather than focus on what might be an erroneous question. But you're right.

Comment: @pinkgothic: I mean, I am just guessing that this is what the OP means with *not returning the required result*. Could also be something else ;)

Comment: Edited, given that answers should strive for completion. :)

Comment: @Felix Kling: Probably. But he did quote `rsort()`. I have the bad habit of asking questions when all I want to do is make people think about *their* question. ;)) Thanks.

Comment: asort() arsort() keep keys and values association intact

Comment: Guys i am going to show you the real data what i am getting and what i want it to be


$array = array('1','2','5','9','5','1','2','1','5');

$new_array = array_count_values($array);

print_r($new_array);

returns

Array ( [1] => 3 [2] => 2 [5] => 3 [9] => 1 )

i want to sort data by the value in desc order it should come

[9] => 1
[2] => 2
[1] => 3
[5] => 3

thanx

Comment: @umermalik: Yes, and `asort()` will do that. Is it not working for you?

Comment: @pinkgothic: i used it but it sort the key not the value i need to sort according to value and lowest to hiest

Comment: The key and the value both are numeric is that making any problem??

Comment: @umermalik: I'm quite confused. I tested your data and it gave me the right result with `asort()`. What you describe sounds like `ksort()`. Hold on, I'll share.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use [`asort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php):

> This function sorts an array such that array **indices maintain their correlation with the array elements** they are associated with. This is used mainly when sorting associative arrays where the actual element order is significant.

---

`rsort()` was wrong from the first place anyway (and so are any other sorting functions that have the `r` (for *reverse*) in it), as it would sort the array from *highest* to *lowest*.

`asort()` sorts from *lowest* to *highest*:

```
<?php
$array = array('f'=>1, 'a'=>2, 'c'=>5);  
asort($array);
print_r($array);
```

gives

```
Array
(
    [f] => 1
    [a] => 2
    [c] => 5
)
```

---

**Note**: These functions sort the arrays **in-place**. They **do not** return a sorted array. The return values is:

> (..) `TRUE` on success or `FALSE` on failure.

Comment: +1 for a pretty nifty, thorough explanation of `asort()`, plus caveats.

Answer (score 3):

Try using **[`asort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)** or **[`arsort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php)** or any other **[sort function that maintains index association](http://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)**.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`asort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) PHP function.

Answer (score 0):

`asort()` is array sort, not ascending sort.

`dsort` doesn't exist. The function you are looking for is `arsort()` - array reverse sort.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php

Answer (score 0):

Use this to sort by [values]:

```
$array = array_count_values($array);
ksort($array, SORT_REGULAR);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Just a thought;
asort - sorts ascending (low to high)

perhaps try

dsort - descending (high to low)